# In MySQL how to query 2 columns from 1 row?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

In MySQL table cardToCard has 1 row each time a credit card balance is transferred from one card to another card.

```
create table cardToCard (
  id int, 
  dt date,
  card_from int,
  card_to int,
  amount decimal(6,2),
  primary key (id)
);

insert into cardToCard values (1, '2014-01-01', 100, 101, 200.00);
insert into cardToCard values (2, '2014-01-01', 101, 102, 200.00);
insert into cardToCard values (3, '2014-01-01', 102, 103, 200.00);
insert into cardToCard values (4, '2014-01-01', 103, 104, 200.00);
insert into cardToCard values (5, '2014-01-01', 104, 100, 200.00);
insert into cardToCard values (6, '2014-01-01', 99, 104, 200.00);
```

Query which card has been used 3 or more times.

```
select card, count(*) 'count'
from
  (
  select card_from 'card', dt
  from cardtocard
  union all
  select card_to 'card', dt
  from cardtocard
  ) d
group by card
having count >= 3
```

The results are correct.  The question is would it be more efficient to write this as a self join?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/420e72/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the most efficient way to write this query would be to start with a list of cards and then do:

```
select c.card,
       ((select count(*) from cardTocard ctc where ctc.card_from = c.card) +
        (select count(*) from cardTocard ctc where ctc.card_to = c.card)
       ) as cnt
from cards c
having cnt >= 3;
```

Then, you need two indexes:  `cardTocard(card_from)` and `cardTocard(card_to)`.

This should use the index for the aggregation, which is typically faster than a file sort.

EDIT:

Using the structure that you are using, it can be faster to do aggregation in the subqueries as well as the outer query:

```
select card, sum(cnt) as cnt
from ((select card_from as car, count(*) as cnt
       from cardtocard
       group by card_from
      ) union all
      (select card_to as card, count(*) as cnt
       from cardtocard
       group by card_to
      )
     ) d
group by card
having count >= 3;
```

This can be faster because the volume of data for the subqueries is smaller than just `union`'ing them together.

Comment: Picard: "Are you certain, Mr. Data?" ;-)

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge . . . No, I'm not certain.  As with most performance conjectures, it should be verified on a particular system.

Comment: Problem is c.card does not exist, not sure how to fix it.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/420e72/1